# Enthought Canopy Editor. Reading documentation with TAB complete

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

Using the Enthought Canopy python editor, when I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> I can get help to appear.

for example, if I type

> In [110]: absolute(**< TAB >**

This brings up a pop-up window showing the docstring for this function. At the bottom of the window it says **"[Documentation Continues...]"**

How do I move to the next page of the documentation?

I've tried everything I can think of and I cant find anything in the canopy help pages nor anything from simple google searches..

Any help is much appreciated

-Jason

Comment: Try hitting <space> to jump to the next page or `h`/`j`/`k`/`l` or arrow keys to move up and down.  It will depend on what you have set as your "pager", but most use those keys.  Windows doesn't have a pager program or much of anything else by default, so I'm not sure what Anaconda is using there.

Comment: I'm running on win7. Typing any character just seems to enter that text into the editor. This includes 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l' and 'space'. I've never heard of anaconda.. (still new to python!)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "canopy" instead of "anaconda" (Anaconda is a competing python distribution very similar to Canopy).  The problem you're describing sounds like it might be related to `readline` not being installed.  It's not strictly required for `ipython` to work, but a lot of features wont' work properly without it.  Try installing `pyreadline` through canopy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately I don't think that's it either. I went to the Package Manager and searched for pyreadline but it showed that it's already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; this is a limited length tooltip / flyover. To see the entire docstring, use the standard ipython method:

```
absolute?
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can scroll this, then press <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd> when you are done.

Comment: Aha! THANK YOU! I was trying all kinds of keyboard shortcuts.